# speedup leaflet map refresh after zoom change

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet

I want the "old" map to be erased quicker after a zoom change.  For example: at zoom level 16, I can see a city name, but when I zoom into zoom17... that city name is not in view anymore... which works... but there is always a little delay before the old map data goes away.

I've seen how to change the zoom animation speed... but not this specific thing.  I think it might have to do with the fact that I'm working with a transparent map...

It feels like a setTimeout function to erase the 'old' map at the previous zoom level. I just want to speed it up.

EDIT:  I looked through the code and found this function: _onZoomTransitionEnd
and saw that it was attached to a timeout, but I changed the timeout time and it didn't seem to do anything.

EDIT#2:  Upon further investigation... I'm getting this problem in leaflet .7.7.  but not the most recent version of leaflet (1.0.1 and beta).  HOWEVER, the most recent version doesn't load tiles during a panning operation... it waits until the pan is done until loading tiles.  Leaflet 77 doesn't do this, it loads 'on the fly'.  So I guess I have two options:    Use the map with a delayed zoom-delete of the previous layer.... or use a map with nice quick zoom response... but a delayed response on rendering new tiles when panning to different places on the map.  I'm thinking option #1 is probably the least disruptive.

EDIT #3:  And now everything is working on Leaflet 1.0.1   so maybe I was just going crazy.  Once again, thankyou to the people making leaflet... you are amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be interested in [`zoomAnimation`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-zoomanimation) map option.

When this option is turned to `false`, Leaflet no longer stretches tiles from pervious zoom level, until tiles of new zoom are received. Instead, the map "blinks" due to the instant removal of all previous tiles.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/152/

Comment: This is great... except when using a phone with no zoom animation... it's simply not going to work.  You have no idea where the map is zooming when you start the zoom... you just magically appear somewhere after all is said and done.  Try turning off zoomAnimation in a mobile phone and you'll see what I'm talking about